# How do I install CakePdf Plugin compatible with Cakephp 2.7.3?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

I am working on a Cakephp 2.7.3 application and I need to install CakePdf  Plugin.

So far all I've found is the CakePdf version that requires Cakephp 3.0+, including when I try using composer and GitHub.

Am still not an expert in CakePHP. Kindly Assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CakePDF release 1.0.3](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/tree/82750dd13574a084daeff21fc76fabf40352bfeb) is compatible with CakePHP 2.x.

To install it, add the following to your `/app/composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "friendsofcake/cakepdf": "1.0.3"
    }
}
```

and run

```
localhost:~/path/to/cake/app$ composer update
```

Comment: thanks @Inigo Lemme try it, sorry to bother you, where is the location of `composer.json` ?

Comment: Iit should be in `/app/composer.json`. I've edited my answer. Make sure it's a valid json file.